# Curved corners IE 7,8 Issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

i tried to set border radius to a td element, but it isn't work on IE7 and IE8
i tried all possible solutions but it still not working 
here's my css classs :

```
padding: 5 5 5 5;
background-color: gray;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #888;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px#888;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #888;
zoom: 1;
filter: alpha(opacity=70);
opacity: 0.7; 
behavior: url(../Bin/PIE.htc);
```

i tried to use PIE.js and it also not working.

Comment: No dice. Trying to add CSS3 functionality to IE7, 8 is like trying to force the evolution of a neanderthal by clubbing it in the head with a stone mallet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE7 and IE8 don't support CSS3 rounded corners. You will need to look to other IE specific solutions if you want to emulate this.

[How to create rounded corners in ie 8 and <](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Cross_Browser_CSS3_Rounded_Corners-16638.html) is one method using .htc controls for IE.

I need to add that no solution to your problem I have ever found is 100% they all have drawbacks and can never have the full functionality that CSS3 offers.